# Why mysql stored function keeps deleting all rows?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make mysql stored function for deleting user with userID parameter, but when i call procedure it deletes all of my data.

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `delete_user`(IN userID INT)

BEGIN

DELETE FROM users
WHERE userID=userID;

END
```

I want to make it to delete only one with right ID.

Comment: you might want to rename the input parameter to something different because "userID = userID" will be always true. It's like writing `WHERE 42=42`.

Comment: Thank you it works now!